# iOS- Howto change the image and property of a button by clicking it?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, google-maps-sdk-ios

In my app, I am having a mapView and a button on it, the button is used to toggle the mapView between a standard mapView and the satellite view.

[image]
Here is the snap shot, if I press the satellite button, the mapView should get changed to sattelite view and the button image should get changed to the following image,
[image]
And now wen the button is pressed it should get changed to a normal mapView.

```
//mapView
camera=[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:13.45 longitude:80.93 zoom:6];
mapView=[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height) camera:camera];
mapView.myLocationEnabled=YES;  
//button
satellite=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
satellite.Frame=CGRectMake(250, 300, 65 , 65);
[satellite setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Satellite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[satellite addTarget:self action:@selector(satelliteView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
[self.view addSubview:satellite];
```

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: have you try `setBackgroundImage` method?

Comment: @johnMa, Ithink U couldnt understand my question.

Comment: try tag value to identify map

Comment: I am gettin g 4 errors like Property 'tag' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Comment: satelliteView:(UIButton*)sender use this.

Comment: Still I am getting this error.

Comment: I replaced, sender.tag using button.tag in the if loop, it is working, thanks to every one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple :

Try using the tag for the UIButton . By default assign tag as for standard mapView For Ex mapButton.tag = 100;

```
    - (IBAction)mapSatelliteSegmentControlTapped:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        if(sender.tag == 100)
        {
              self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
              // Change the MapButton image as well as tag 
               self.mapButton.tag = 101; // 
              [self.mapButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapSateliite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
              self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
              // Change the MapButton image as well as tag 
              self.mapButton.tag = 100; // 
              [self.mapButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapStandard.png"] 
        }

}
```

Comment: I am using google map api, not mapkit

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a single button to toggle between two types of maps, you have to keep track of the button's state. Lets say your button is by default showing a normal Map view.

`@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL isSatelliteMap;`

Make it FALSE when the view loads for the first time as `isSatelliteMap = NO;`, This means that you will be loading `MKMapTypeStandard` for the first time & button will show `SatelliteImage`.

Now when the button is pressed:

```
-(void)ButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if(!isSatelliteMap)
    {
        //set MKMapTypeSatellite
        self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonMapNormal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        isSatelliteMap = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonMapSatellite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        isSatelliteMap = NO;
    }
}
```

This thing you can apply to any type of Map. I mean you can do same thing for google Maps.
Hope this helps.

Comment: no, this doesnt works

Answer (score 1):

you can put below code in touch up inside method for change button image

```
-(void)settalite:(id)sender{

    UIbutton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: I have done this, check this link, https://maps.google.co.in/ press the satellite button in the map,  the map and the button will change ,the same thing I have to do,

Comment: you can set satellite UIButton tag to different tag to map tag

Answer (score 1):

I just give you suggestion, Add your `MKMapView` in button click method and also give tag of button such like. *(In your case Change **GoolgeMap**)*

```
myButton.tag = 101;
```

And following is button method.

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *) sender
{
   if(self.mapView)
   {
      [self.mapView removeFromSuperView];
   }   

   self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
   self.mapView.frame = self.view.bounds;       
   [self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
   [self.mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
   [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
   [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];

   if(sender.tag ==101)
   {
      [self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
      [btnGoHome setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"changedImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
      sender.tag = 100; 
   }
   else
   {
      [btnGoHome setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"previouseImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
      [self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
      sender.tag = 101; 
   }
}
```

And add button on `self.view` and don't forget to write

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:buttonName];
```

Comment: I am using google map api, not mapkit

Comment: Then change it with google map.. map is not important logic is helpful for you.. :) thanks :)

Comment: instead of sender.tag, I used [sender tag], it minimised my errors, but, twp errors are coming while assigning the values of the tag, [sender tag]=101;    Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an Objective-C message not allowed

Comment: Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an Objective-C message not allowed

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)satelliteView:(UIButton*)sender
{
    switch (sender.tag) {
        case 0:
            sender.tag=1;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"standardImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            break;
        case 1:

            sender.tag=0;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapSateliite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using google map api, not map kit